# What algorithm does ByteBuddy's ElementMatchers#nameStartsWith use?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

Let's suppose that I want to apply an `@Advice.OnMethodEnter` to the methods declared in `org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext`. To do that, I've written this minimal agent:

```java
public class SequenceAgent {

  public static void premain(final String args,
                             final Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
        .type(nameStartsWith(
            "org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext"))
        .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
            .method(any()).intercept(Advice.to(SequenceAdvice.class)))
        .installOn(instrumentation);
  }

  public static class SequenceAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void enter(@Advice.This Object thiz, @Advice.Origin Method method,
                      @Advice.AllArguments Object... args) {
      String className = thiz.getClass().getName();
      String methodName = method.getName();

      System.out.println("Entered: " + className + "#" + methodName);
    }
  }
}
```

I expected this configuration to filter out `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` as it doesn't match `org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext` but looks like invocation of methods on objects of this class are also intercepted:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext;

public class AgentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext();

        context.containsBean("SomeBean");
    }

}
```

When attached to the agent and ran, it prints out (wrapped for readability):

```
Entered: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
    AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    #getResourcePatternResolver
.
.
.
Entered: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
    AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    #getResourceCache

Entered: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
    AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    #getClassLoader

Entered: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
    AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext
    #containsBean
```

And the class hierarchy for `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServe.ApplicationContext` is:

```
org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader
        ⇧
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
        ⇧
org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext
        ⇧
⤏⤏⤏⤏ org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
        ⇧
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext
        ⇧
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServe.ApplicationContext
```

And the `containsBean` method is declared and overridden in:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory#containsBean
        ⇧
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext#containsBean
```

Why for `containsBean`, `@Advice.This Object thiz` is resolved to `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` and not `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte Buddy uses String.startsWith.

What you are seeing is due to Byte Buddy instrumenting classes, not instances. In a way, think of Byte Buddy copying the advice code into the target method.

As a result, all subclasses will be affected. For doing what you are doing, you need to check the instance class's type during invocation, just as if you wanted to implement this in Java.

Comment: Do you mean when the `GenericWebApplicationContext` class is instrumented, all the methods declared in its super-classes are also instrumented? As `containsBean(...)` is not declared in `GenericWebApplicationContext`, but in its `AbstractApplicationContext` super-class.

Comment: All inherited methods, yes. Byte Buddy literally changes a class as if you had changed it in the source.

Comment: But IIRC, `GenericWebApplicationContext.java` does not have `containsBean` in its source code -- it's definied in one of its superclasses.

Comment: You can verify that easily by adding Thread.dump() to tge advice.